# JavaScript event not triggered (sync connection with websockets)

Tags: javascript, events, websocket

I'm developing an app with websockets. I have an event that it's called when a message it's received but it doesn't fire if I have a loop.
What I'm trying to do it's a sync connection (only for this part, that's why I'm using websockets). My idea it's to wait until the message received it's what I expect and then continue the program flow.

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.hostname + ':8888/')
var msgAck=false; //Flag that comes true when received data

connection.onmessage = function (event){
  check(event.data);
}

function check(msg){
  if(msg == "ok")msgAck=true;
}

function requestOk(){
  connection.send("somecmd");
}
//Normal program flow
requestOk();//Server will return "ok"
while(!msgAck);//Wait server response
```

The `onmessage` event it's never triggered so the program get stuck there.

Comment: `while(!msgAck);//Wait server response` is not what you should be doing... you should either use callbacks or promises to handle the asynchronous flow. (Your while loop is just infinitely cycling because it's stuck there)

Comment: What does the server code look like? Please add a sample of the called code to the question as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50467930/edit)

Comment: @Luca It's a microcontroller. When it receive a command, send a response to client. In this case when it receives "somecmd" it sends "ok".

Comment: @CodyG. I don't know what you mean. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: You never send "somecmd"

Comment: My bad, edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a while loop to wait for asynchronous responses, you must utilize the event based architecture. If you need to wait for a specific message, you should include a unique identifier for that message.

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.hostname + ':8888/')    
connection.onmessage = function (event){
  check(event.data);
}

function check(msg){
  if(msg == "ok"){
    // msgAck Function
    foo(); // call a function here instead of using a while loop
  }
}

function requestOk(){
  connection.send("somecmd");
}
//Normal program flow
requestOk(); //Server will return "ok"
```

I mention callbacks and promises, because in general you can rewrite events into callback/promise oriented flow.

```
function requestOk(cb){
  var connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.hostname + ':8888/')    
  var check = function(msg){
    if(msg == "ok"){
      // msgAck Function
      cb(null,msg)
    }else{
      cb("Message not okay.")
    } 
  }
  connection.onmessage = function (event){
    check(event.data);
  }
  connection.send("somecmd");
}
//Normal program flow, callback style
requestOk(function(err,data){
  if(err){
    // Error message
  }else{
    // OK msg
  }
});
```

Comment: But what if the function I want to call it's in another file and the file it's loaded after?

Comment: the "check" function? ( i don't understand your question at all)

Comment: The "foo" function that you mentioned above.
The problem it's the program needs the response to continue (because it's part of data in the real case, not an "ok") so I must wait until the server give me that. My question it's if there is a way to "wait" (stop the program flow) until the `onmesage` event it's triggered.

Comment: `foo` will not be called until the onmessage event fires, as I have written it, and there is nothing you need to program flow besides not calling functions after `requestOk` --- if you need to call functions after the message you need to write them inside the event function, such as I have done with `foo`. There is also nothing stopping you from defining `foo` outside of the event function and passing parameters to it.